# Given two iterators of items, how can I calculate the added, kept, and removed items between the two?

Tags: rust

If I have two iterators, one representing the previous state of some collection, and one representing the current state, is there a one liner to calculate a tuple containing the items that have been added to the current state, kept between the two, and removed from the current state?

I could do this manually fairly simply, or create my own function, but I'm curious if this exists already.

Something like this: (untested)

```
fn delta<'a, T: PartialEq>(past: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>, present: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>) -> (Vec<&'a T>, Vec<&'a T>, Vec<&'a T>) {
    let past = past.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let present = present.collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let added = present.into_iter().filter(|x| !past.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let kept = present.into_iter().filter(|x| past.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let removed = past.into_iter().filter(|x| !present.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
    (added, kept, removed)
}
```

Comment: If the iterators are sorted, then you can be clever by using [`Itertools::merge_join_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.merge_join_by) and do it in a single pass.

Comment: If your data is not sorted, then take a look at HashSet here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_set/index.html, it has Intersection, Union, Difference functions which do what you need. It is simple to use and much better than Vecs.